# Laravel Dusk - can't make it run on GitLab CI

Tags: php, laravel, docker, gitlab-ci, laravel-dusk

Did anyone get to make Laravel Dusk to work on GitLab CI?

I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/lorisleiva/laravel-docker) docker image, which is amazing, but I simply can't execute `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux`, it says:

`/bin/bash: line 102: ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux: No such file or directory`

When I enter at `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin` I can see that `chromedriver-linux` is there and it's executable, but can't make it run.

By now, the script lines that compose this phase are:

```
- mv .env.testing .env
- php artisan key:generate
- ./vendor/bin/phpunit --colors=never
- php artisan dusk:install
- chmod -R 0755 vendor/laravel/dusk/bin
- ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux
- php artisan dusk
```

I've also tried the [approaches on documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk#continuous-integration), even though they're not for GitLab CI, but none of them worked.

**Update:**

Running `ls -l ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin` returns:

```
total 33560
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      10885776 Jun 26 13:10 chromedriver-linux
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      14994520 Jun 26 13:10 chromedriver-mac
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       8393728 Jun 26 13:10 chromedriver-win.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         69309 Jun 25 22:59 jquery.js
```

I've tried to copy the file to the machine's current `PATH` but didn't work either:

#### Testing the $PATH variable

```sh
$ echo $PATH
./vendor/bin:/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

#### Copying the binary to `/usr/local/bin`

```sh
$ CHROME_DRIVER_PATH_BIN=./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux
$ cp $CHROME_DRIVER_PATH_BIN /usr/local/bin
```

#### Testing if the file is really there

```sh
$ ls -lha /usr/local/bin
total 56564
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jun 26 17:33 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Feb 21 23:08 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       10.4M Jun 26 17:33 chromedriver-linux
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.8M Feb 22 06:40 composer
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root         118 Feb 21 23:02 docker-php-entrypoint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root        1.4K Feb 21 23:02 docker-php-ext-configure
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root        2.4K Feb 21 23:02 docker-php-ext-enable
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root        2.3K Feb 21 23:02 docker-php-ext-install
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root         587 Feb  9 01:57 docker-php-source
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          32 Jun 26 17:33 heroku -> /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         817 Feb 21 23:08 pear
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         838 Feb 21 23:08 peardev
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         751 Feb 21 23:08 pecl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           9 Feb 21 23:08 phar -> phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       14.5K Feb 21 23:08 phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       14.3M Feb 21 23:08 php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       14.2M Feb 21 23:08 php-cgi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        2.6K Feb 21 23:08 php-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       14.4M Feb 21 23:08 phpdbg
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.5K Feb 21 23:08 phpize
```

Either way, running `chromedriver-linux` does not work, I got the error 
`nohup: can't execute 'chromedriver-linux': No such file or directory`

I've tested the same concept on my macOS: created an executable, put it into a folder which is on my `PATH` variable using a symlink and it works perfectly.

Comment: What's the result of `ls -l ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin`? Is it a 64-bit system?

Comment: I've updated the question with this information. And yes, it is a 64-bit system

Answer (score 2):

I could solve that installing `chromium` and `chromium-chromedriver` packages since they are available on Alpine Linux.

Below is the **relevant** part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: lorisleiva/laravel-docker

before_script:
  - apk add chromium-chromedriver -y
  - apk add chromium -y

phptest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mv .env.testing .env
    - php artisan key:generate
    - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --colors=never
    - chromedriver 2>&1 &
    - sleep 5
    - nohup php artisan serve &
    - php artisan dusk
```

Also, a **really important part** is to add `--no-sandbox` argument when creating the `RemoteWebDriver`. This can be done changing the function `driver` on `tests/DuskTestCase.php` file:

```php
<?php
    // tests/DuskTestCase.php
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox', // # Add this # //
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
                $options
            )
        );
    }
```

Just this solved my problem and now I can test with Dusk on GitLab CI using `lorisleiva/laravel-docker` Docker image.

Comment: is there any way I can cache the chromedriver installation so that it does not install on every test run?

Answer (score 0):

The [Dockerfile for that `lorisleiva/laravel-docker` image](https://github.com/lorisleiva/laravel-docker/blob/9e2f99153d824e2ed946d422259973c8868c631f/latest/Dockerfile#L59-L70) does:

```
ENV PATH ./vendor/bin:/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
...
WORKDIR /var/www
```

So when your script does execute, the '`.`' in '`./vendor`' might not reference the current working directory you expect.

Since `PATH` is set, it would be best if `chromedriver-linux` was in `./vendor/bin` instead.
That way, your script can simply call `chromedriver-linux` (no leading path)

Comment: I've tried copying the file directly to /usr/local/bin but this didn't solve either. I updated the question's content with something that might be useful.

Comment: @juniorgarcia I didn't suggest to copy the binary, only to use its full complete path.

Comment: @juniorgarcia Anytime you are using '`./`', you are assuming you are in a certain place. Don't assume.

Comment: I know that, but if I run tests like `test -f ` and `test -x` with the path starting with `./` to certify myself that the file exists and it's executable, shouldn't it work?

Comment: @juniorgarcia Yes, it should. I simply advise to do that for testing purpose, to rule out any path issue.

Comment: Ok! I genuinely ask because there could be any gotcha about that that I didn't know about.